# ant design collapse - open all

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and Ant Design. Ant design's collapse widget allows all items to be open, but there is no way pre-baked way to set the items to be all open by default - you can only set a single collapse unit to be default opened with

```
defaultActiveKey={['1']}
```

How would I default open all?

Comment: defaultActiveKey={yourCollapseArray.map((_,index)=>(index))} is best answer for dynamic collapse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use `activeKey` property

```
activeKey={['1','2','3']}
```

Comment: the problem with these answer is that you can't collapse the panel after that, you should use the defaultActiveKey

Answer (score 7):

You can use `defaultActiveKey` for that case.

As you see below it will accept an Array(also number and string)

```
defaultActiveKey?: Array<string | number> | string | number;
```

So you can do:

```
defaultActiveKey={['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']}
```

But **do not** use `activeKey`, because can not close the panels unless you want to force open them all panels without any option to be closed.